# Get numerical part of a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string like "1000/Refuse5.jpg" or "50/Refuse5.jpeg".
Note that the first section of string-in this examples 1000 or 50-is variable.
I want to get the "5" number from this strings by C# methods.
Can someone help me?

Comment: use a substring function to grab everything before the "/" character and then convert that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more constrained regular expression.

```
var fileName = "1000/Refuse5.jpg";
var match = Regex.Match(fileName, @"(?<=\D+)(\d+)(?=\.)");

if(match.Success)
{
    var value = int.Parse(match.Value);
}
```

Comment: Forgot to take out my linqpad specific stuff.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Regex

```
string input = "1000/Refuse5.jpg";
var num = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+").Cast<Match>().Last().Value;
```

Comment: Why have the overhead of Last() when you can have the regex parser just look at the last item and not process the whole string. See my post.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner regex:

```
Console.WriteLine (Regex.Match("123ABC5", @"\d", RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Value); // 5
```

Note if the last number will be more than one digit use `\d+` instead.

Comment: RightToLeft - good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to extract the relevant part of the string and then convert that to an integer. You'll need to study your input set and ensure though that the regular expression you use fits your needs.

```
        string input = "1234/Refuse123.jpg";

        // Look for any non / characters until you hit a /
        // then match any characters other than digits as many
        // as possible. After that, match digits as many as possible
        // and capture them in a group (hence the paranthesis). And 
        // finally match everything else at the end of the string
        Regex regex = new Regex("[^/]*/[^\\d]*([\\d]*).*");

        var match = regex.Match(input);

        // Group 0 will be the input string
        // Group 1 will be the captured numbers
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
```